# SSL Certificate on Load Balancer

Tags: ssl, load-balancing

I have a load balancer in front of multiple websites, one of which needs an SSL certificate. When I install the SSL certs for that one site on the load balancer, it breaks the HTTPS protocol for all the other sites.

How can I get SSL for this site without disrupting HTTPS for the other sites? Can I just get an SSL cert for the whole load balancer? The URLs are different and do not share top level domains.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of load balancer do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the website(s) behind the load balancer, it sounds like you might need a wildcard cert for *.yourwebsite.com , or something similar if all URLs behind the balancer share a common URL.

You could also generate a cert for one of the specific sites with something like [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: So Let's Encrypt would be used individually for each site and there would be no SSL configuration on the load balancer?

Comment: Site != server.

Comment: Yep- each site could have its own SSL cert generated by Lets Encrypt- and because it is a free generator and the certs only last 3 months, you could set up a cron job to generate a new cert when they expire- [here is how you can set that up.](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-automatically-renew-certificates/4393)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Let's Encrypt to generate a single certificate that's valid for many domains. The downside is that you will need to regenerate the certificate whenever you add a new domain. Depending on how frequently you do this, you may run into rate limiting from Let's Encrypt...

Here's how you'd request a cert with multiple domains:

```
certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/example/ -d www.example.com -d example.com -w /var/www/other -d other.example.net -d another.other.example.net
```

Here's how you would add another domain to an existing certificate:

```
certbot --expand -d existing.com -d example.com -d newdomain.com
```

Finally, please use Let's Encrypt's test servers/API until you have finalized your scripts/commands, otherwise you may hit the rate limit sooner... just add `--staging` to your certbot commands.

I hope this helps!

- [Relevant discussion at Let's Encrypt](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/host-multiple-domains-with-a-single-certificate/20917)
- [CertBot Documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#re-creating-and-updating-existing-certificates)
- [Let's Encrypt Rate Limits](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/)
- [Let's Encrypt Staging Environment](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/staging-environment/)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) and SSL stripping. You should run a virtual host for each SSL domain on your webserver which will then balance the stripped traffic the same way the unencrypted traffic is balanced.